# On Azure accessing token using Curl command working fine when I used same in my app is giving error : invalid_scope

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am using `CURL` request:

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'client_id=123489hfdufkd924449&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=sjksjaadwq928449282348djffegke&grant_type=client_credentials' 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/3422823dkfhskflswlewr9328402948/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

> Note:client_id and client_secrets are invalid here .

When I tried the same from the app its giving me error : invalid_scope

So what is the issue why is it not working ..?

This is where I am adding the information

```
def _get_token_from_client_credentials(self, endpoint, client_id,
                                       client_secret, service_mgmt_url):
    '''
    Get token from azure with client credentials.
    :return string of the token
    '''
    ilog.debug('self = %s, endpoint = %s, client_id = %s, \
        client_secret, = %s, service_mgmt_url = %s'
        % (self.__dict__, endpoint, client_id,
           client_secret, service_mgmt_url))
    if "v2.0" in endpoint:
        payload = {
            'grant_type' : 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' : client_id,
            'scope' : 'https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default',
            'client_secret' : client_secret,
        }
    else:
        payload = {
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'client_id': client_id,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'resource': service_mgmt_url,
        }

    response = self.send_request_no_token(
        Url.make_from_url(endpoint), method=HTTP_METHOD_POST, data=payload)
    status_code = response.status_code
    try:
        response_doc = json.loads(response.body)
    # In case of http error, we don't get json object.
    except ValueError:
        response_doc = {'error': response.reason_phrase}
    if status_code != '200':
        err_msg = response_doc.get('error',
                                   'failed to get authentication token')
        raise AzureHttpError(err_msg, status_code)
    return response_doc.get('access_token')
```

function to make a call

```
def send_request_no_token(self, url, method=HTTP_METHOD_GET, headers=None,
                          data=None):
    '''
    Send HTTP request with provided parameters. Authorization token
    is not added to headers, following http redirect is turned on.
    :return http response object
    '''
    ilog.debug('self = %s, url = %s, method = %s, headers = %s, data = %s'\
        % (self.__dict__, url, method, headers, data))
    # Use empty Content-Type header if header is not given.
    if headers is None:
        headers = {'Content-Type': ''}

    ilog.debug('self = %s, url = %s, method = %s, headers = %s, data = %s'\
        % (self.__dict__, url, method, headers, data))
    return self._send_request(url, method=method, data=data,
                              headers=headers, follow_redirect=True)
```

Where the actual call happens

```
def _send_request(self, url, method=HTTP_METHOD_GET, headers=None,
                  data=None, follow_redirect=False):
    '''
    Send HTTP request with provided parameters, which is managed by
    HTTP session.
    :return http response object
    '''
    data = urlencode(data if data else {})
    self._connector.request = HTTPRequest(
        is_secure=url.is_secure, port=url.port, hostname=url.host,
        path=url.path, params=url.params, method=method, body=data,
        headers=headers, follow_redirect=follow_redirect)
    self._connector.execute_request()
    return self._connector.response
```

I am not getting where i went wrong

Comment: which app, have you specified proper content type ?

Comment: My application where i want to make call to azure API, and Content-Type is empty.

Comment: The curl request works fine, right? If so, you need to provide your application code here.

Comment: @TonyJu added the code

Comment: @ajeyhiremath Have you tried with `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` as the scope in your code?

Comment: @TonyJu Yes I tried Which is not giving me the error but Using this SCOPE I cannot get vnet, VM and subnet information. To get those informations(vnet, VM and subnet) what SCOPE should I use?

Comment: @ajeyhiremath How did you get vnet, vm and subnet information?

Comment: @TonyJu If I use version1 endpoint(https://login.microsoftonline.com/3422823dkfhskflswlewr9328402948/oauth2/token) to get token and by calling the azure API's(Ex:GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2019-03-01) then I can get those (vnet, vm and subnet) information

Comment: You should use `https://management.azure.com/.default` as the scope for v2.0 endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For microsoft graph api, the resource endpoint is `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

For Azure management api, the resource endpoint is `https://management.azure.com`.

If you want to use v2.0 auth endpoint to call azure management api, you should use `https://management.azure.com/.default` as the scope.

Comment: Hi @Tony.  i used above curl command and got token as well. But I'm facing scope issue when using access_token in consumption apis. I used scope https://management.azure.com/.default while creating token and app has contributor role also. what step i'm missing here. Thanks